# "as" as a preposition?

Tags: prepositions

Could you help explain the usage of 'as' in these two sentences?

> 1. The parents looked upon their children as their pride and joy.
> 2. People looked upon the situation as critical.

In sentence one, 'as' is a preposition since it's followed by nouns. Am I correct? Why is 'as' followed by an adjective in the second sentence?

Comment: The prep "as" is not restricted to just NP complements. In your second example the adjective is a predicative complement. It's predicative because it is related to a predicand, i.e. "situation". Note that this "as" is the prepositional analogue of the verb "be" (cf. "the situation was critical."). Compare also "I regard his behaviour **as unacceptable**".

Comment: ... and 'I see this room as needing painting'.

Comment: Non-finite clauses can function as complement of "as", but unlike the OP's examples they are not predicative, and hence irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [1] *The parents looked upon their children* [*as their pride and joy*]. [NP]
>
> [2] *People looked upon the situation* [*as critical*]. [AdjP]

This use of preposition "as" is not restricted to just NP complements.

In both examples the complements of "as" are predicative complements in that they refer to a predicand, "their children" in [1], and "the situation" in [2].

Note that this "as" is the prepositional analogue of the verb "be" (cf. *The situation was critical*. / *Their children were their pride and joy*).

Compare also

> *They chose her* [*as secretary*]. [NP]
>
> *I regard him* [*as indispensable*].  [AdjP]